# Data will not shown at Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.2 data set dialog

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I  have faced suddenly the following issues with Jaspersoft Studio data set dialog:

**First:** After running the first query `select KN_Perzentile  from  "Kennzahl"  where  KN_ID = 215 and KN_RefWert1 = 8.3` and clicking the refresh preview data the Studio shows that 2 fields are read (which should be one in fact as I tested the query against DB), but the data will not shown at all!

**Second:** Running **any other query** there encounters an error, saying that the field **KN_Perzentile** is not found! This field is not asked in the second query at all!

Both queries are tested against Database and correct. I have these problems only on one project.

The variable **vVisual** should read the value from the data base.And the java class which is in build path should read his variable and use it for creating the chart. But the data will not be added to the chart. I guess that is because jasper does not read the KN_Perzentile.
This is the chart with Visual Basic = 0 after genarating:
[image]
Here is the jrxml:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JFreeReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1edc4d15-06d0-46cf-8d57-179fd0bed566">
<scriptlet name="BoxPlotScript" class="testProjektIman.toc.JFreeChartScriptlet"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select KN_Perzentile  from  "Kennzahl"  where  KN_ID = 215 and KN_RefWert1 = 8.3
]]>
</queryString>
<field name="KN_Perzentile" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<variable name="Pie" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable" calculation="System">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Pie}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{Pie}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="vVisual" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="First">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Perzentile}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Perzentile}]]> </initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<detail>
    <band height="290" splitType="Stretch">
        <image scaleImage="Clip" hAlign="Center">
            <reportElement x="60" y="50" width="440" height="215"  uuid="60c9de91-e7ad-4ffb-81fd-109a381532b6"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$V{Pie}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Java Class:

```
public class JFreeChartScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet

{

@Override
public void afterReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {
    Double testVb = 0.0;
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    testVb = (Double) this.getVariableValue("vVisual");
    dataset.setValue("Java", new Double(43.2));
    dataset.setValue("Visual Basic", testVb);
    dataset.setValue("C/C++", new Double(17.5));
    dataset.setValue("PHP", new Double(32.5));
    dataset.setValue("Perl", new Double(1.0));

    JFreeChart chart =
        ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
                "Pie Chart 3D Demo 1",
                dataset,
                true,
                true,
                false);

    PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setStartAngle(290);
    plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    plot.setNoDataMessage("No data to display");
    this.setVariableValue("Pie", new JCommonDrawableRenderer(chart));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

I don't see any use of any field out of the result. `$V{Pie}` just refers to itself and is being used in the reports `Detail` band, `$V{vVisual}` is being calculated but not being used anywhere.

Because of this structure, no fields are being shown.

**Second**

There is a `field` defined called `KN_Perzentile`. If you *change your query* and your query does not return this field (with the correct data type) anymore you get the error you are seeing.

**EDIT**

According to the [documentation for scriptlets](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/), there are two rules to comply with:

> The important part when ensuring a variable in your report template is filled by a Scriptlet (or subreport) is to ensure the Variable has a calculation type of 'System' in the report design:
>
> ```
> <variable name="AllCities" class="java.lang.String" calculation="System"/>
> ```
>
> Also notice that there is *no* Variable Expression. Make sure you remember these two points when creating Variables in your own report with values supplied by Scriptlets.

Following this, the `variableExpression` of the `system` variable should be removed.

Comment: I have updated and put the java class. vVisual is supposed to get the value from the DB and the java class pass this value in order to be used for drawing the pie chart